# How to enable the sound effect on touching a button?

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, soundeffect, onclicklistener

If I implement the `OnClickListener`, the sound effect will work on clicking the button. While on implementing the `OnTouchListener` the sound effect doesn't work on touching it. So how to enable the sound effect on implementing the `OnTouchListener`?

**EDIT:**

Here is the code if I use clicking approach:

```
public class CalculatorActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    //...
    private Button btn1;
    private EditText edLCD;
    //...

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //...
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.d1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

        edLCD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edLCD);
    }

    //...

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        edLCD.setText(edLCD.getText().toString() + "1");
    }
}
```

And here is the code if I use touching approach:

```
public class CalculatorActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{
    //...
    private Button btn1;
    private EditText edLCD;
    //...

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //...
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.d1);
        btn1.setOnTouchListener(this);

        edLCD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edLCD);
    }

    //...

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            edLCD.setText(edLCD.getText().toString() + "1");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code. Also why do you want to do this for a 'touch' action and not for a 'click' action?

Comment: @MisterSquonk Touching a button gives faster response, while clicking on it won't respond until you raise your finger from the screen. Besides, what code should I show to you? I just ask for the way of enabling the sound effect on touching the button.

Comment: Just use onClick, it's not expected for some button to react onTouch and not onClick. Don't break the UX!

Comment: @DanielLockard Actually, there is no difference between `onTouch` and `onClick`, they both are similar except for the responsive time.

Comment: @Eng - show the code for the OnTouchListener that doesn't work. We can't tell you how to get it to work until we see what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try...

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        v.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
        edLCD.setText(edLCD.getText().toString() + "1");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. We got there in the end. :)